# How do i remove a character from each line of a text file using python?

Tags: python, list, text-files

I want to remove the \n that comes at the end of every line of a text file as i need to put each line as a separate list item in a list.

```
with open("PythonTestFile.txt", "rt") as openfile:

    for line in openfile:
        new_list = []

        new_list.append(line)

        print(new_list)
```

This is what i get

```
['1) This is just an empty file.\n']

['2) This is the second line.\n']

['3) Third one.\n']

['4) Fourth one.\n']

['5) Fifth one.\n']

This is what I want

['1) This is just an empty file.']

['2) This is the second line.']

['3) Third one.']

['4) Fourth one.']

['5) Fifth one.']
```

Comment: `new_list.append(line.strip('\n'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `string.strip()`

```
with open("PythonTestFile.txt", "rt") as openfile:
    new_list = []
    for line in openfile:
        new_list.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

    print(new_list)
```

Comment: Using `.strip` without argument removes whitespace characters, not only newline, so for example if line end is space it would be discarded too. It is better to use `.strip('\n')` which would discard only newline character.

Comment: @Daweo good point; editing my answer to use `rstrip('\n')`

Comment: a@Daweo and @cmac thank u soo much guys

Answer (score 1):

```
line = line.rstrip('\n')
```

This will take the newline character at the end of the line off.